# CiviDiscount does not show new events

Tags: civievent, cividiscount, civicrm-home

I am quite new to CiviCRM.

My question is:  when I create a new Event via Manage Events and then go to add a discount to that event,  CiviDiscount does not show the new event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please also tell us which version of CiviCRM you are using with which CMS?

Comment: CiviCRM 4.6.24. (Drupal 7)

Comment: You say CiviDiscount is not showing the new event - which page are you looking at?  Is it Administer > CiviDiscount > New Discount Code or somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe, you should make sure if it isn't caching issue. Clear browser, civi cache etc.

Comment: I have cleared the cache as well . still the same